# Filebeat logs to Logstash connection

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to make filebeat forward logs to logstash as a deb service(/etc/init.d/logstash start). When I run the logstash executable in my terminal pointing to the config file this connection seems to work. There has to be something slightly off with my configuration or understanding of how to run logstash as a detached service.

**Environment**

2 AWS hosted ubuntu servers, no security group and/nacls blocking the connection

Filebeats installed on my application servers

- filebeat.yml passes configtest
- filebeat stays running as a service

Logstash installed as deb on a master server

- logstash.conf passes config test and is saved in /etc/logstash/conf.d
- Elasticsearch is commented out in logstash.conf
- logstash is running as a service
- logstash.conf Permissions-> -rw-rw-rw- logstash logstash logconsolidated.log
- No cert/ssl/tls keys/encryption are being used at this time

**Filebeat config**

```
filebeat:
 # List of prospectors to fetch data.
      prospectors:
          paths:
            - /opt/somedirectoy/test/log/mylog.log
          input_type: log
  ### Logstash as output
  logstash:
    # The Logstash hosts
    hosts: ["10.10.10.10:5044"]
```

**Logstash.conf**

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "/opt/logstash/output/log-consolidated.log"
    }
  }
```

Comment: In order to understand more about your logstash as a service, please check the file /etc/init.d/logstash. Post this file here. You can open it as a text file and see what directory has been specified as default config directory. Sometimes we need to edit this file to suit our requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the worker count in filebeat.yml as below?

```
  ### Logstash as output
  logstash:
    # The Logstash hosts
    hosts: ["10.10.10.10:5044"]
    # Number of workers per Logstash host.
    worker: 1
```

You should add worker count in the logstash configuration